# imbushuo/mac-precision-touchpad: Windows Precision Touchpad Driver Implementation for Apple MacBook / Magic Trackpadの設定

Tags: windows-10

相談したいこと

imbushuo/mac-precision-touchpad: Windows Precision Touchpad Driver Implementation for Apple MacBook / Magic Trackpad

出典参考記事はこれです
https://news.mynavi.jp/techplus/article/20220330-2307385/3
-WindowsでMacのマジックトラックパッドを使う方法
掲載日 2022/03/30 14:58
著者：後藤大地
「AmtPtpDevice.inf」というファイルがあるので、このファイルを使ってドライバのインストールを行う。ファイルエクスプローラで「AmtPtpDevice.inf」ファイルを右クリックするとメニューに「インストール」が表示されるので、これを選択すればよい。

課題は「AmtPtpDevice.inf」が見当たらない
ので
解決を助けて頂きたい
Zoomか電話で直接教えて頂きたく
探しているメンター
分かる方
実際にやってみて試してください

Zip展開した先がこちらのフォルダー以下です
[image: Screenshot_2023-10-24-06-59-22-036_com.microsoft.skydrive.jpg]

それをさらにダブルクリックすると以下画像です
[image: Screenshot_2023-10-24-07-06-58-964_com.microsoft.skydrive.jpg]

この中に、AmtPtpDevice.infが見当たりません

上から二番目、AmPtDeviceをダブルクリックするとこの画像が出てきます

[image: Screenshot_2023-10-24-07-21-22-139_com.microsoft.skydrive.jpg]

それを開くを押すと、こちらです
メモ帳アプリに記載されたamptdevice.infが出てきます
これが出てくるだけでダウンロードできません
[image: Screenshot_2023-10-24-07-22-47-999_com.microsoft.skydrive.jpg]

どこのタイミングで何をすれば、AmptDevice.infインストールできますか?
また、それをインストール出来ないのは、セキュリティの問題でしょうか?
Windowsを使っています、versionは10です。
何を見てどう判断されたか、ご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Windows defender, Windows defenderの除外設定など実行してみましたが、結果全てメモ帳にAmptDevice.infのメモ帳が出て来ただけでした